# Action Intent like feature in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have some document like a pdf, doc and excel file. In android we used Action Intent that helps to open such files or prompt with the software that are available in our phone to open that. I would like to do the same using phonegap. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you can show that files inside the `inAppBrowser` plugin

Install it with

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

and use it like this:

```
window.open('path/to/your/file', '_blank');
```

On android that files can't be displayed inside the `inAppBrowser`, but you can use `_system` option to launch an intent that will show the apps that can open the file:

```
window.open('path/to/your/file', '_system');
```

You can use `_system` on iOS too if you want other app to open the file

Answer (score 0):

try to use this plugin. i used it to display pdf file.

https://github.com/cyberkatze/pdfViewer

For other purpose you have to edit the native code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file opener plugin

https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    '/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'application/pdf', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: and what about word excel or image file?

Comment: It should be able to open all kinds of files, pdf is just an example